# Read new lines with NSScanner

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsscanner

I'm trying to read the characters between words in a string.

```
    NSCharacterSet* whiteSpace = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" \n\r\t"];

    NSScanner* testScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"space newline\n space space newline\r end"];

    while([testScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
        NSString* spaceBetweenWords = @"";
        [testScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:whiteSpace intoString:NULL];
         [testScanner scanCharactersFromSet:whiteSpace intoString:&spaceBetweenWords];
        NSLog(@"x%@x", spaceBetweenWords);
}
```

the output is:

```
xx
xx
xx
xx
```

I would expect it to be:

```
x x

x

x

x x

x 

x
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

`NSScanner` skips white space by default.
To fix, add:

```
[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];
```